# Create BigDecimal from unscaled long

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to convert long 1099 to BigDecimal 10.99;
This gives me 11.00:

```
long cost = 1099;
MathContext CENTS = new MathContext(2,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
BigDecimal result = (new BigDecimal(cost,CENTS)).movePointLeft(2);
```

AFAIK this should work.  What's my bonehead error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that there's a distinction between scale and precision.  The constructor of `MathContext` accepts a precision, which is a *total* number of decimal digits on either side of the decimal point.  (For example, the original `BigDecimal` you had was essentially `11 * 10^2`, as if it were in scientific notation.)

Change it to `new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`.

Comment: When I set the scale as well after changing precision to 8: (new BigDecimal(cost,CENTS)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).movePointLeft(2) it returns 10.9900

Comment: Missed the edit window... Setting the precision to 8 resulted in 10.99, BTW.  I'm starting to make dumb mistakes so it's probably time to quit for the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
new BigDecimal( 1099L )
.movePointLeft(2)
```

Use constructor taking only a `long`, without the `MathContext`.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2LDFfk).

Comment: Yes, but I over engineer everything.  This is money so if anyone operates on the field I want to make sure it rounds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`BigDecimal.valueOf(long unscaledVal, int scale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-long-int-) method:

```java
long cost = 1099;
BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.valueOf(cost, 2);
System.out.println(result); // 10.99
```